# Express.js body parser throwing weird error

Tags: express, body-parser

I'm trying to use new built in body parser in my express app.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.json());
```

My package:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "canvas": "^2.9.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "gm": "^1.23.1",
    "pngjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rpi-led-matrix": "^1.11.1"
  }
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../encodings'
Require stack:
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/raw-body/index.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/body-parser/index.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/express/lib/express.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/node_modules/express/index.js
- /root/freeflow-display-adapter-v2/out/index.js
```

There really isn't such dependency in my node_modules, but even if I install "yarn add encodings" it still throws the same error.

Comment: I'm facing this problem as I updated my VPS's `node` from v16 to v20.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this problem as I updated my VPS's `node` from v16 to v20. The fix involves updating `babel`'s setup. I don't know if you use `babel` but, if you do, here's how I fixed it:

1. I updated my `package.json`. Ensure that the only `babel` packages that you are depending on are the following ones: `"@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1"` for `dependencies` and `"@babel/cli": "^7.23.4", "@babel/core": "^7.23.6", "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.6"` for `devDependencies` (versions may vary).
2. This I'm not sure is needed but it doesn't hurt: delete `package-lock.json` and `npm i` again.
3. Change your `import 'babel-polyfill';` to `import '@babel/polyfill';`.

Comment: Cant really verify if this will fix the issue. Don't even remember how I resolved it.